# Edits timestamps showing as answer timestamps

Tags: support

[This fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35059038/343302) has a timestamp that looks like this:

[image: wrong timestamp]

However, the author states that this is an [edit timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18956643/3), not an answer timestamp. Indeed, that seems to be the case:

[image]

I had downvoted the answer based on the timestamp (it looked like a copy of the accepted answer which was posted three years prior), but I now see that the answer deserved an upvote instead.

**Why is this answer displaying the wrong timestamp?** If other answers are displaying this same issue, then it needs to be fixed. Had I not left a comment explaining the reason for the downvote then this issue would have not come to light.

Comment: You misunderstand - it's the **other** answer that's been edited after techturbulence posted their answer.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify:
It **wasn't** displaying the wrong timestamp.
The link shows:
A user answered this question.
I added new info (about PHPdoc)
Then the user edited their (earlier) answer to include my info, rendering my answer redundant.

A new question might be:
**How can we prevent earlier answers being edited in order to gain more points through copy-pasting?**

Furthermore, **should** we do this, since we can never tell the intent of such an edit - it's fine to improve an answer. SE is about providing quality answers, crediting the right person for their info is secondary.

I didn't want a duplicate answer (D.R.Y, right?) so I removed mine.